# is it possible to keep particular applications in light theme while whole Ubuntu is in dark mode?

Tags: 22.04

I want to use Talend open studio on Ubuntu 22.04.1. i wish to keep whole system in dark mode while if possible TOS i could use in light theme? here is comparison between TOS light/dark theme. TOS in dark mode is barely usable.

Light Mode
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ic6x.png

Dark Mode
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/emGge.png

is it possible that i could edit some parameters in .ini file of TOS? which looks like

```
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1536m
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
--add-opens
java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Comment: You can have a config that keeps one type of apps *light* (eg. Qt5) whilst others apps are *dark* (eg. GTK3/4) as they'll use different configs, which is why some apps are out of *sync* with others (GTK2 using a different config to more modern GTK3 for example), but I know nothing about *talend open studio* and thus not what it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i managed to figure it out.

1. create a .desktop shortcut
2. Edit desktop shortcut (desktop entry)

Exec=env GTK_THEME=adwaita:light /Programs/TOS_BD/TOS_BD-linux-gtk-x86_64 --unity-launch %F

now launching application using this shortcut always lauches TOS in light theme.
I got help from https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/10/how-to-use-different-gtk-3-theme-for.html

thank you for all the help folks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had to do the same to compiz config manager.
if it is gtk 3 we can add this to the desktop file command line:
env GTK_THEME=4CLIX-LG /usr/bin/ccsm

if it is qt 5  we can add this to the desktop file command line:
env QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum /usr/bin/kolourpaint %u
but also needs a theme set as an application theme in kvantum manager

Comment: I am sorry, i am a beginnner to Ubuntu.. I am unsure what information can i provide for you to help me out? i tried searching these various terms in your answer but I can't figure it out. i am using Ubuntu with Gnome desktop environment.